# Not able to publish Rest message from solace to http listner?

Tags: rest, solace

Trying publish rest message from solace to http listener.

But configured rest delivery points, consumer, queue-binding status are down 
:( (Note: Admin status is up)

Http listener link: http://hostname:port/ws/simple/getDefaultRDP

added the screen shots Please let me know any changes need to be done

[rest delivery point status screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35kyC.png)

[rest consumer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSi3g.png)

[queue binding screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hlcP.png)

screenshot for (a)show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-delivery-point * detail

[show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-delivery-point * detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5poQ.png)

screenshot for (b) show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-consumer * rest-delivery-point * detail

[show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-consumer * rest-delivery-point * detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWL4c.png)

screenshot for (c) show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-delivery-point * queue-binding * detail

[show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-delivery-point * queue-binding * detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwPS3.png)

Note: Http listener is a Dellboomi process and listner working fine when i did test with soap ui test tool

Comment: The screenshots don't show enough detail. What are the outputs of (a) `show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-delivery-point * detail` (b) `show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-consumer * rest-delivery-point * detail` (c) `show message-vpn sol-vpn rest rest-delivery-point * queue-binding * detail` ?

Comment: Hello Wai Leong thanks you for your response adding screen shots to query for mentioned commands :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operational status of a Rest Delivery Point (RDP) depends on the operational statuses of its Rest Consumers and Queue bindings.

In this case, the command:

```
show message-vpn <vpn_name> rest rest-consumer * rest-delivery-point <rdp_name> detail
```

shows the last failure reason as:

```
Host Name Resolution Failure
```

This means the Solace router is unable to resolve the remote hostname to an IP address and thus cannot connect to your http listener.

You'll need to put in a resolvable FQDN as the remote, or an IP address as the remote host.